# Get preloaded file in android

Tags: android, android-file

I'm new to android development and I am working on a little project. What I am having some issue with is getting access to preloaded files.

In my app, I have an XML file that I preloaded (I just simply put it in my src folder in a package). How do I access them in my classes? I need to get a File object pointing to this file so that I can use it as I would I/O files. It seems like this should be trivial, but alas I am stuck.

Lets say the file is located under: com.app.preloadedFiles/file1.XML

I've tried something along the lines of this, but have had no success:

```
URL dir_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("preloadedFiles/file1.XML");
FIle file = new File(dir_url.toURI());
```

Comment: Do you necessarily need a File object, would an InputStream be sufficient if so rather than using the ClassLoader I would suggest using the the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) provided for you in the android SDK. It's a simple class you use, you just need to create a folder called 'assets'.

Comment: I need it to be a File. I have a number of functions that deal with File objects and its associated operations, and it would be big hassle to update them for InputStreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in my app by getting an InputStream to the file -- something like:

```
myContext.getAssets().open(fileName);
//read the data and store it in a variable
```

Then, if you truly need to do `File` related opterations with it, you can write it to a private (or public) directory and do your operations from you newly written file.  Something like:

```
File storageDir = myContext.getDir(directoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File myFile = new File(storageDir + File.separator + fileName);
//then, write the data to the file and manipulate it -- store the name for access via File later
```